# AngularJS Multiselect checkbox dropdown with Selected Checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a Simple Multiselect checkbox dropdown. As I have given below.

```
<select name="edit_tags" class="form-control" id="advisor_article_tagsx" multiple="" required>
      <option ng-repeat="service in services" value="{{service.id}}">{{service.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now I want that some checkbox like index 1,3,5 comes with selected checkbox.

My AngularJS Code is given below.

```
$scope.article_edit = function(articles) {
  $scope.services = [$scope.model[0], $scope.model[1]];
}
```

Then What I need to do for that ??

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in developers console?

Comment: In Console, I did not find any error or exception.

Comment: Is `$http` call in the same controller as `advisor_article_edit` method?

Comment: Yes, In the same controller.

Comment: Can you please set up a working fiddle to illustrate the problem you are facing? Since it is hard to say what is actually wrong with your code seeing this short examples. Try initiate `$scope.selected = []` before using it in `$scope.advisor_article_edit` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use ng-options which has good support & also ng-model on select field. So your template can be:

```
<select name="edit_tags" class="form-control" id="advisor_article_tagsx" multiple="" 
 required ng-model="selected" ng-options="service as service.name for service in services">
</select>
```

[**Working plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LlHUaJO6B7hi47PTWR1Q?p=preview)

Comment: You want to show checkbox inside select? That's not default behavior of select field. You need some library for that like this http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main Check this example: http://embed.plnkr.co/xWvfWYjaW7TThKZONkv5/

Comment: Hello Shantanu, I have updated my question. If you don't mind then can you please help me little more. I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: @JohnBrad plnkr.co/edit/c90dKXgLOHJn00aN9f3u?p=preview and also check this if you ant to run it just inside that function only: plnkr.co/edit/YhRcshKy0qUfR1wVufY6?p=preview